# Create perfect multithreaded model for different sort of tasks for window service

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, windows-services

I am writing a window service. I have some set of task to be executed once a day. Some set of task should  executed after ever time interval say 5min. And last some set of task should be executed after a time interval say 72hours.

Meanwhile i have some set of settings need to be refreshed at certain time interval.

I am finding bit problem in designing it properly. This is my design for it.

```
public void StartController()
        {
            try
            {               
                readSettings();                
                startDetectionAndPost(); //once a day
                LogUtil.WriteLog(LogLevel.INFO, "starting bootstrap");
                bootStrap(); //based on time interval elapsed
                LogUtil.WriteLog(LogLevel.INFO, "starting heartbeat of agent");
                startHeartBeat(); //after a time interval say 1 min                
                LogUtil.WriteLog(LogLevel.INFO, "start fetching ADSI info");
                startInfoTimer();

                while (true)
                {
                    if (!IsRunning)
                    {
                        engine.StopExecution();                       
                        break;
                    }
                    //here got to change this as per threading model.
                    while (_threadMonitor.CurrentThreadCount >= MAX_JOB_COUNT)
                    {
                        if (!IsRunning)
                        {
                            engine.StopExecution();
                            LogUtil.WriteLog(LogLevel.INFO, "query execution stopped");                            
                            break;
                        }
                        //otherwise sleep
                        Thread.Sleep(100);                        
                    }

                    _executionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(engine.StartExecution));
                    _threadMonitor.IncrementThread();
                    _executionThread.Start();

                    //if user gone stop service it will timeout issue.
                    Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));//_agentCache.DomainSweepInterval));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtil.WriteLog(LogLevel.ERROR, "could not process."+ex.Message,ex);
                //log exception and what to do next.
            }
        }
```

The task I have to perform once a day, or like heartbeat after every minute. I created timers for that and started it because these things are independent of others.  But then the main execution part. Where i have two types of query to execute. 
1) after every interval say 5 min and other a interval after every 72hours. Only once can execute at a time.
2) I have to refresh my settings on a give time interval, say after 5 min, I have to refresh other two settings say once after 30min and other after 60min.

Now I am finding difficulty in arranging it properly so that my service start/stop will not be affected and everything should be perfect designed as per scalability and performance?

Please share your views, I hope my question is framed properly.

Thanks

Comment: If you have actions that need to run on a scheduled basis run them in Windows Task Scheduler, rather than re-implementing it. Create a "standard" executable that takes command line parameters and carries out the appropriate task based on them, then create scheduled tasks to invoke your executable to perform said tasks. A Windows Service is not a good fit for what you're doing.

Comment: I personally dont prefer that, as the schedule time here in my case can keep changing. say it was 72 hours for one customer and can be 1 hour for another. Here every thing is dynamic and controlled from server.

Comment: In that case, create a tool that manages windows scheduled tasks. Have your UI for modifying schedules remove incorrect tasks, add new tasks and update existing ones. Writing a Windows Service to perform the same job as the Windows Scheduler is **hard** and more to the point, *Microsoft have already got it right for you*. Leverage what's already available =) If you insist on creating a service, don't have threads that sleep, use timers to raise events at the appropriate time that you react to by running the appropriate code for each timed "activity" that you need to perform.

Comment: I am not at all interested in windows schedule task option. I hate it and its not as per given requirement. I have to do what I have been assigned to do. I dont want to play with requirements.

Comment: this is how for one time job i created a timer which will run only at night 12:00 when network is free.
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Local);
            TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(detectAndPost);
            //if(DateTime.Now<dt)
            _tmrDetector = new Timer(callback, null, (dt - DateTime.Now), TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

Comment: why not quartz.net? (http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @sunder: Your delay is going to fail if Daylight Saving Time is involved. There will be 25 hours between midnight on Saturday and midnight on Sunday. So the job will start at 11:00 PM on Sunday night. And in the spring there are only 23 hours, so your job will start an hour later than expected. If you want to use that delay timer, convert your starting date/time to UTC before you do any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

First I agree Task Scheduler has its issues.  I have had to write one of these before, but it I was starting from scratch I would look at this project.

http://taskschedulerengine.codeplex.com/

This enables you to climb on the back of other developers and you can focus on the actual business issue. Also if you find something you want to add you can give back to the comunity

Comment: I have resolved the issue myself but still i will look for some professionals to provide their views. I will post my code later.